# Lost data on an external hard drive

Tags: external-disk, data-recovery

I wanted to install the macOS Big Sur installer onto a thumb drive however I didn't have any that had large enough storage to fit it so I decided to install in on my external drive which had more than enough space.

Much to my chagrin it turns out that doing this deletes all the data previously stored on it. My question is: is there any way to retrieve this data or is it gone forever?

Comment: It is impossible to tell from the info you provided if it is even possible (HD or SSD? macOS version? etc.) But generally speaking erasing a drive doesn't delete the data on it, just marks the formerly used space as available (over simplifying here). So if nothing was then written to the external drive your data is likely there and may be recoverable. But if it is now a (bootable) Big Sur installer it is likely at least some data is gone forever. It would be best to unplug the drive and investigate data recovery utilities and companies that recover data from erased and damaged drives.

Comment: You should restore this important data from your backup of that data.

Comment: Ok. I don't think its an installer because all my files from my computer were put on it. Does that mean all the previous data is most likely gone?